# How to zoom a buffered image?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Plagiarism checker software. Till now I have created a buffered Image which converts any text written in an text area into a `png`,`jpg`,`jpeg`, `gif` format.

When I open the image text written inside the image is shown too small and it is shown properly only when I manually zoom my screen from keyboard or Mouse.

I have tried several techniques to zoom out or reposition the image but failed. How could I achieve a zoomed in image?

Here is my Code.

```
 String text = textArea.getText();

 Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40);

 FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

//get the height and width of the text

 Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(text, frc);
 int w = (int) bounds.getWidth();
 int h = (int) bounds.getHeight();

String[] parts = text.split("\n");

//create a BufferedImage object
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h * parts.length,      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);



//calling createGraphics() to get the Graphics2D
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

//set color and other parameters
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.setFont(font);



int index = 0;  
for(String part : parts){
 g.drawString(part, 4000,  h * index++);
    }

 g.dispose();
```

Comment: Have you tried using AffineTransform?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Comment: `g.scale` likewise

Comment: Yup I did but it didn't work for me

Comment: @JoopEggen I also tried that but it didn't work ...... the problem I found right now is that my programe increases the size of image according to the length of string inserted into the text Area .. how can I get rid out of that!!